# Null check operator used on a null value When I refresh the homepage or go to the homepage

Tags: android, flutter, dart, null

i think i need help here. My code says error "Null Check Operator Used on A null Value". When i running/build the app for first time everything is oke. The apk running goodly. But when me click home button or refresh the TextSpan recognizer, the null check alert is showing. Can you see the code below and give me the solution for this problem issue. Sorry if my english bad, i hope you understand the problem guys. PLSS HELP :)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:adhan/adhan.dart';
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart' as MyLocation;
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hijri/hijri_calendar.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:muslimapk/pages/kiblat_page.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int currentIndexPage = 0;
  String locale = 'id';
  final location = new Location();
  String? locationError, _timenow, _datenow, _tglHijriah, _hari;
  String? MylocationCountry, MylocationCity , shalatTime ;
  PrayerTimes? prayerTimes;
  double? latitude, longitude, pLat, pLong;
  HijriCalendar? _todayhijr;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _todayhijr = HijriCalendar.now();
    _tglHijriah = _todayhijr!.toFormat("MMMM, dd yyyy H");
    _timenow = "${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute} }";
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:1), (Timer t)=>_getCurrentTime());


    if (DateTime.now().hour >= 05 && DateTime.now().hour <= 06) {
      shalatTime = "Subuh";
    }if (DateTime.now().hour >= 06 && DateTime.now().hour <= 07) {
      shalatTime = "Matahari Terbit";
    }if (DateTime.now().hour >= 12 && DateTime.now().hour <= 15) {
      shalatTime = "Dzuhur";
    }if (DateTime.now().hour >= 15 && DateTime.now().hour <= 18) {
      shalatTime = "Ashar";
    }if (DateTime.now().hour >= 18 && DateTime.now().hour <= 20) {
      shalatTime = "Maghrib";
    }if (DateTime.now().hour >= 20 && DateTime.now().hour <= 05) {
      shalatTime = "Isya";
    }

    getLocationData().then((locationData) async {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      if (locationData != null)  {

        setState(() {
          prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(
              Coordinates(locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude),
              DateComponents.from(DateTime.now()),
              CalculationMethod.karachi.getParameters());
          pLat = prayerTimes!.coordinates.latitude;
          pLong = prayerTimes!.coordinates.longitude;
          print("Latitude : $pLat, Longitude : $pLong");
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          locationError = "Couldn't Get Your Location!";
        });
      }
      List<MyLocation.Placemark> placemarks = await MyLocation.placemarkFromCoordinates(pLat!, pLong!);
      setState(() {

        MylocationCountry = placemarks.reversed.last.country.toString();
        MylocationCity = placemarks.reversed.last.locality.toString();
        print("Country : $MylocationCountry, City : $MylocationCity");
        print("Tanggal hijriah : $_todayhijr");
        print("Time Now : $_timenow");
      });
    });

    //DateTime.now().hour >= 18 && DateTime.now().hour <= 19

    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HijriCalendar.setLocal(locale);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(225),
        child: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                final prayerTimes = this.prayerTimes;
                if (prayerTimes != null) {
                  return RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: MylocationCountry ?? "NULL",
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
                          },
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "\n$MylocationCity" ,
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
                                },
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              ),
                            ),
                            WidgetSpan(
                              alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.refresh_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )

                            ),
                          ],
                      )

                  );
                }
                if (locationError != null) {
                  return Text(locationError!);
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.white,
                );
              }
          ),
          flexibleSpace: ClipRect(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("lib/images/masjidil-aqsha.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                      Color(0xFF002700).withOpacity(0.50), BlendMode.darken)
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(200),
            child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(shalatTime ?? "NULL",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.white),),
             SizedBox( height: 10 ),
              Text(_timenow ?? "NULL",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    color: Colors.white),),
              SizedBox( height: 10 ),
              Text( _tglHijriah ?? "NULL",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.white),),
              SizedBox( height: 10 ),
            ],
            ),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(0))
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 250,
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: "$_datenow",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "\n$_hari",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ))],
        ),
      ),

      extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                final prayerTimes = this.prayerTimes;
                if (prayerTimes != null) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Prayer Times for Today',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text('Fajr Time: ' +
                          DateFormat("HH:mm").format(prayerTimes.fajr),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Sunrise Time: ' +
                          DateFormat("HH:mm").format(prayerTimes.sunrise),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Dhuhr Time: ' +
                          DateFormat("HH:mm").format(prayerTimes.dhuhr),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Asr Time: ' +
                          DateFormat("HH:mm").format(prayerTimes.asr),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Maghrib Time: ' +
                          DateFormat("HH:mm").format(prayerTimes.maghrib),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Isha Time: ' +
                          DateFormat("HH:mm").format(prayerTimes.isha),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                if (locationError != null) {
                  return Text(locationError!);
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.white,
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
          style: TabStyle.react,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF018700),
          top: -20,
          items: [
            TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Beranda'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.navigation, title: 'Kiblat'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.calendar_month, title: 'Kalender'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.settings, title: 'Pengaturan'),
          ],
          initialActiveIndex: currentIndexPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            currentIndexPage = index;
            if(index == 0) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
            }
            if(index == 1) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/kiblat');
            }
            if(index == 2) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/calendar');
            }
            if(index == 3) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/settings');
            }
          }
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<LocationData?> getLocationData() async {
    var _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    var _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    return await location.getLocation();
  }

  void _getCurrentTime()  {
    setState(() {
      _timenow = DateFormat('hh:mm').format(DateTime.now());
      _datenow = DateFormat.yMMMMd("id").format(DateTime.now().toLocal());
      _hari    = DateFormat.EEEE("id").format(DateTime.now());
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried to make checknull with "!" but the alert still showing. This happened when i go or refresh the home route.

Comment: Please share the crash log, which line creates the crash? Without it, helping you might be difficult.

Comment: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Directionality
  Directionality:file:///C:/Users/MHD%20PATI%20PERDANA/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.5/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_mate
  rial_app.dart:328:12

Comment: any idea for resolving this problem sir?

Comment: i think the error is here : _todayhijr = HijriCalendar.now(); when in first open the app the home page, this code still work, but when i click the home page button again, the error showing.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely goes wrong on this line

```
  List<MyLocation.Placemark> placemarks = await MyLocation.placemarkFromCoordinates(pLat!, pLong!);
```

Your code will come there even when `pLat` and `pLong` are `null`. This happens when `locationData` is null. I believe you would actually like to exit the function when that happens so you need to return in the end of the `else` like this:

```
      if (locationData != null)  {

        setState(() {
          prayerTimes = PrayerTimes(
              Coordinates(locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude),
              DateComponents.from(DateTime.now()),
              CalculationMethod.karachi.getParameters());
          pLat = prayerTimes!.coordinates.latitude;
          pLong = prayerTimes!.coordinates.longitude;
          print("Latitude : $pLat, Longitude : $pLong");
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          locationError = "Couldn't Get Your Location!";
        });
        return; //ADD THIS
      }
```

Without it your code just continues below it.

Comment: thanks sir for your idea, but i think this null problem is because the hijri package not have data when i go to another page and back to home page. When i erase the hijri calendar variable the error is gone. I new in flutter. i hope you can understand me and help me sir.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem clearly. The solution is I put the var hijri to below  Widget Build like this :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HijriCalendar.setLocal('en');
    var _hijrCalendar = HijriCalendar.now();
```

thank you so much for everyone who tried to help me.